# Routing of a query with endswith operator to the logical partition in Cosmos db with hierarchical partition

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have an azure cosmos container setup with hierarchical partition keys.
I have the id set as partitionKey and userId set as the hierarchical partition key.

Now if I do a query that has ENDSWITH, would this query be routed to the single logical partition and physical partition.

```
SELECT c.id, c.userId FROM c WHERE c.id = 'users' AND (ENDSWITH(c.userId,'60000000') OR ENDSWITH(c.userId,'7760000000'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query will be routed to a subset of physical partitions and logical partitions based on your first hierarchical partition key `id`. Technically that could be a single physical partition if all logical partitions that use the same `id` happen to be on that physical partition.

It'll still be a cross partition query for that subset though as you would need an exact match for the `userId` to scope it to a specific logical partition.

Assuming you have indexed the `userId` property (or are using the default indexing policy where all properties are indexed) the query will result in a full index scan for the `userId` property, which will linearly increase RU usage based on the amount of documents for that `id`.

Comment: As a note; Having the `id` as first hierarchical key seems counterintuitive. I would strive for having the `id` be unique on its own or within a (sub)partition which is not defined by it own value. Even though you could use it the way you use it now, it's more of a category than an identifier for a document.

Comment: Is it possible to setup indexing on a hierarchical partition key? Here in my case userId is a hierarchical partition key and when I tried setting up indexing on that property it gives me this error ```\"Errors\":[\"The special mandatory indexing path \\\"\\/\\\" is not provided in any of the path type sets. Please provide this path in one of the sets.\"```

Comment: You'll need to add `/*` to the excluded paths. It's mandatory in either the included or excluded paths. If you decide you don't want to index all properties by default you'll need to move the `/*` from included to excluded.